# group number of counts by category

Tags: python, nltk

I wrote a script that goes over data, checks for emoticons using regex, and when an emoticon is found the counter is updated. Then, the number of counts per category should be written to a list for example cat ne has 25 emoticons, category fr has 45.... Here is where it goes wrong. The results I get are:

> [1, 'ag', 2, 'dg', 3, 'dg', 4, 'fr', 5, 'fr', 6, 'fr', 7, 'fr', 8, 'hp', 9, 'hp', 10, 'hp', 11, 'hp', 12, 'hp', 13, 'hp', 14, 'hp', 15, 'hp', 16, 'hp', 17, 'hp', 18, 'hp', 19, 'hp', 20, 'hp', 21, 'hp', 22, 'hp', 23, 'hp', 24, 'hp', 25, 'ne', 26, 'ne', 27, 'ne', 28, 'ne', 29, 'ne', 30, 'ne', 31, 'ne', 32, 'ne', 33, 'ne', 34, 'ne', 35, 'ne', 36, 'ne', 37, 'ne', 38]

The fileid is of this form, one big file contains 7 smaller files (each file is a category). Within the category files are around 100 files per category:

> data/ne/567.txt

The data in each of the .txt files is just one sentence, and looks like this

> I am so happy today :)

This is my script:

```
counter = 0
lijst = []  
for fileid in corpus.fileids():
    for sentence in corpus.sents(fileid):
        cat = str(fileid.split('/')[0])
        s = " ".join(sentence)    
        m = re.search('(:\)|:\(|:\s|:\D|:\o|:\@)+', s)
        if m is not None:
            counter +=1
            lijst += [counter] + [cat]
```

Comment: do you have an example of the input data?

Comment: @SaulloCastro I edited my question to include information on the input data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

```
import collections

counts = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for fileid in corpus.fileids():
    for sentence in corpus.sents(fileid):
        cat = str(fileid.split('/')[0])
        s = " ".join(sentence)
        counts[cat] += len(re.findall('(:\)|:\(|:\s|:\D|:\o|:\@)+', s))
```

Comment: Thanks very much, now everything is grouped for category!

Comment: When try to state this as a definition for use in a larger script, I keep getting errors for the definition. I would just call the definition emoticons(corpus), but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure I understand what's actually the problem, can you paste the code in your question that causes the problem?

Comment: @VictorKerkez I figured it out, I made a silly mistake. Thanks again!